# Can you freely camp along trails in Scotland?

Tags: camping, scotland

I am planning to do a multi-day hike in Scotland, preferably somewhere fairly remote. I am looking for information regarding the legality of camping along the trail. It would seem from [this site](https://www.outdooraccess-scotland.scot/Practical-guide/public/camping) that it is permitted when it is "wild camping". Does this simply apply to anywhere that is not private property? I of course plan to be totally respectful of the land, leave no litter, bury waste, etc.

Comment: This seems completely on-topic here, but you might get better-quality answers to this kind of question at [outdoors.se]. (But please don't repost this question there, since it's already been answered.)

Comment: Note there ARE some places where, due to excessive demand, wild camping is prohibited. Loch Lomond national park has such restrictions (at least in the most popular/accessible parts. It may be the only example, I don't know offhand.

Answer (score 7):

The access rights apply to private land too.

Your link is a part of [this site](https://www.outdooraccess-scotland.scot/) about Scottish Outdoor Access Rights and says the access right extends to camping, but it mentions one national park which prohibits wild camping.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Outdoor_Access_Code) is relevant too, giving detailed descriptions of what land has access rights, and what does not.

The more remote your hiking, the more likely it is to have access rights to the land, with certain exceptions as mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, yes, it is legal to wild camp in Scotland.

The Scottish Outdoor Access Code allows wild camping on pretty much any unenclosed land, the same land which is covered by access rights. Unenclosed land refers to land that isn't gardens, land around buildings, fields under crop or containing livestock and attractions to which an entrance fee is usually charged.

For you that means it is fine to camp along the trail so long as you're not interfering with farming or forestry operations or camping close to someone's house or farm.

Scottish Natural Heritage (a government agency) publish a [guide to wild camping](https://www.nature.scot/sites/default/files/2017-08/SOAC%20-%20Publication%202017%20-%20Camping%20in%20Scotland.pdf) and a [guide to access rights](https://www.nature.scot/sites/default/files/2018-05/Publication%202005%20-%20Scottish%20Outdoor%20Access%20Code.pdf).